# Conexão MVC, qual utilizar MSQLi ou PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, mvc, mysqli

Estou começando a programar um MVC PHP, que tipo de conexão é mais recomendável: MSQLi ou PDO e porque?

Comment: Não há relação entre uma coisa e outra. Não há melhor. Há gostos e eventualmente o que atende melhor um problema específico. MySQLi deveria ser sempre a primeira opção, dificilmente há necessidade de uso do PDO. Algumas pessoas discordam disso, sei lá porque (já ouvi muitas explicações, mas não costumam me convencer, ainda que exista motivo em casos bem específicos, só que o pessoal abusa), então isso é uma questão de opinião e não dá para fornecer uma resposta definitiva.

Comment: Leia a segunda resposta mais votada da pergunta duplicada, ela é a melhor lá.

Answer (score 0):

PDO tem suporte a 12 drivers de bases de dados diferentes e parâmetros nomeados, perde em questão de performance comparada à MySQLi.

Recomendo o PDO utilizando o [Doctrine](https://github.com/doctrine), por questão de flexibilidade com drives e compatibilidade;

[Referência](https://www.turbosite.com.br/blog/pdo-ou-mysqli-qual-usar/)

Comment: Mysqli será removido do php? Onde está a fonte dessa afirmação?

Comment: No PHP 7, as funções mysql_* (como mysql_connect(), mysql_query() e outras) deixaram de existir. Agora é preciso utilizar MySQLi ou PDO. Você afirmou uma coisa que não existe cara...

Comment: Corrigi, muito obrigado, tinha me confundido;